# Skip for loop for None list

Tags: python, python-3.x

for the code below if `lst` is `None` it will throw an exception.

```
for a in lst:
   ..
```

Is there a way to let it just not the execute the loop when `lst` is `None`?

Now I always need to do a check:

```
if lst:
    for a in lst:
       ..
```

Comment: Where the `lst` is coming from and where is this code being used?

Comment: `None` is falsy, so just put the loop in a `if lst:`

Comment: `if lst:`? Have you tried to skip it?

Comment: Check first? Use `lst or []`?

Comment: Updated the question - I wish to avoid the check, just want to know is there an elegant way to put the code

Comment: @jonrsharpe Checking is better. `lst or []` will execute the loop test with `dis.dis("for _ in []:pass")`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `or` operator to loop over a empty list if bool(lst) results in False

```
>>> lst = None
>>> for a in lst or []:
...      print(a)
... 
>>>
```

Comment: Can you see any differences between your answer and mine ?

Comment: When I started typing my answer, I dont think your answer had a `or` version

Comment: @Sunitha In that case, suggest edits to the already existing answer through a comment. We are here to help others and not stack Stack Overflow with duplicate answers. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `if`:

```
if lst:
    for a in lst:
        do_something
```

Comment: Hi, I wish to avoid the check if possible, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
for a in lst if lst else []:
    ...
```

or this is better to just use an `or` to check:

```
for a in lst or []:
```

Comment: Hi, I wish to avoid the check if possible, is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think there is not a way to do this, because you are looking to find out that is a variable is iterable or not, so there is couple of way to check this, but without checking i think no.